# Is this a bug in FunctionDomain (V.10)?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I used

```
FunctionDomain[1/(x^3 + 1), x, Complexes]
```

and got

> 1 + x^3 != 0

Is this a bug in FunctionDomain (V.10)?

Can I receive $x \neq -1$, $x \neq \dfrac{1-\sqrt{3}I}{2}$ and $x \neq \dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}I}{2}$?
With *Maple*, I tried
[image]

If I used

```
FunctionDomain[1/(x^3 + 1), x]
```

I got true answer

> x < -1 || x > -1

Comment: I don't think your Maple comparison is quite fair.  You've explicitly asked Maple to solve an inequality, rather than asked for the domain of a function.  That doesn't account for more complicated examples, as I've placed in my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a bug; it is an implicit representation of the domain.  Note that condition $1-x^3 \neq 0$ cannot be simplified further over the complexes or, at least, `Reduce` doesn't simplify it further:

```
Reduce[1 - x^3 != 0, x, Reals] 
(* Out: x < 1 || x > 1 *)

Reduce[1 - x^3 != 0, x, Complexes] 
(* Out: -1 + x^3 != 0 *)
```

A similar thing can happen over the reals:

```
FunctionDomain[1/(2 + Sin[x] + Cos[Pi*x]), x]
(* Out: Cos[Pi*x] + Sin[x] != -2 *)
```

The expression $\cos(\pi x) + \sin(x)$ is never equal to $-2$, by the way, but `Reduce` can't prove that and I don't think it's reasonable to expect it to do so.  Is this a bug?  Probably not; the answer is correct.

Here's another example:

```
FunctionDomain[1/Sqrt[Sin[1/x] - x], x]
(* Out: x != 0 && x - Sin[1/x] < 0 *)
```

How might we improve this result?  The graph of $x-\sin(1/x)$ crosses the $x$-axis infinitely many times near $x=0$ and at values that are not expressible in closed form.

```
Plot[Sin[1/x] - x, {x, 0, 1/2},
  PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 12]
```

[image]

Considering these types of examples, I think that implicit representations are quite reasonable - even preferable.  In simple cases, it's quite easy to extract out `Unequal` expressions, solve the corresponding equations, and come to the conclusion that you did with Maple.

Comment: Mclure First, thanks to your answer. I think, we want to find the domain of the given function, we must solve the inequality `x^3+1<>0`.